# Order of evaluation for Debug.Assert(condition, interpolatedStringMessage) in .Net 4.5.2

Tags: c#, assert, string-interpolation, operator-precedence

I've stumbled upon a strange problem in C#/.Net 4.5.2 here…

I had a `!ContainsKey()` check in a `Debug.Assert()` with an interpolated string containing the value, if found, like so

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string invalidKey = "invalidKey";

try
{
    Debug.Assert((!dict.ContainsKey(invalidKey)), $"{nameof(dict)} contains the key {dict[invalidKey]}!");
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("AssertionString was interpolated before the check was performed!");
}
```

(only without the try-catch block in my first version)

I would've expected to never run into the `catch` there, as is also the case when e.g. checking the code in .NETFiddle ( see https://dotnetfiddle.net/RyQooW ), however, in Visual Studio, running the code under .Net 4.5.2, I get the following:

[interpolated string evaluated before assertion condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7sje.png)

It's definitely the string interpolation (and not a problem with `ContainsKey`), because when I remove the interpolation from the message, the Exception isn't being thrown.

Is the order of evaluation not guaranteed? I thought the string wasn't going to get interpolated if the assertion was true.

Or is this just an error in this version of the .Net Runtime (maybe an optimisation to interpolate assertion strings early to make them static or something?)

Thanks for any input, and cheers!

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? I've got no exceptions with v4.6.1.

Comment: @dymanoid 4.6.1 as well, on a windows 8.1 system w/ VS 2015 Update 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so for everyone that stumbles over this, too:

It is *not* a bug, apparently, but actually simply `Debug.Assert` being a regular method (not some special built-in helper, etc., see also [Microsoft's reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs,4f55cf5792dfc5e6)), and thus any string argument *has* to be interpolated *before* entering the method (since the objects in question might not be available outside the calling scope).
But since both the conditional and the message are method arguments and the evaluation of the condition happens *inside* the the method (and *not* the method call as a *result* of the evaluation), the `KeyNotFoundException` above is of course thrown before the method is entered and the condition checked.

The only thing that makes `Debug.Assert` sort of special is that is has a `[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute and is thus stripped in non-Debug builds.

So this is actually entirely understandable and proper behaviour (in *any* dot net version), although it is kind of a pitfall.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly like that. It is a regular method, so all parameters' values are computed before the call. Hence, expression for parameter#2 immediately raises an exception. The only way it could be forced into having the other behavior, is to write an `Assert` method that takes a 'generator' like `(bool, Func<string>)` which would be invoked if needed and it'd look like this: `Assert(!dict.contains(x), () => $"Yep, dict contained {dict[x]}");` however.. your assert message looks really strange. I'd personally write `Assert(!dict.contains(x), $"oops it contained key {x}")` since it says KEY

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Uhhh, yeah, I might have jumbled that up when trying to generalise it for posting it on SO m) Do you think it would be necessary to fix it (and thereby bump the question again by editing it?)

Comment: You've asked the question, and even gave a nice answer to it, so I think, let it stay. I just thought that you might have overlooked this silly typo that was the actual cause for exception :) I think it's fine to leave it as it is, cheers.